# is an Activities onPause method called when the screen times out?

Tags: java, android, service, screen, onpause

I'm having trouble understanding the screen timeout function and how that will effect code running in my activities. Does onPause() get called when the screen times out?

I have an activity and a related service running an AsyncTask, which is counting down from 60 seconds. I want to be able to lock the screen, and at the end of the timer, start a new service and new activity that sounds an alarm and vibrates the handset. When the user wakes the phone they should see the new activity, whose display is being updated via a broadcast receiver from the new service.

What I am finding is that the behaviour is highly unpredictable. Once the screen times out, it will usually sound the alarm and bring up the new activity under the lockscreen, but this takes anywhere between 2-4 minutes, and sometimes doesn't happen at all. I seem the get better results locking the screen manually, rather than waiting for a time-out, but it's still unpredictable and varies per handset.

If anyone had any thoughts/suggestions as to whats going on under the hood, and even whether  this approach is sensible, the would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: what is your code? i have some difficulties to understand your question.

Comment: After more investigation I have found that the phone seems to sleep completely when the screen times out. When looking in the logcat there  are one minute blocks where no logs are produced whatsoever (both my own and the system ones). Is there anyway to force a service to be given high priority? I have tried using startForeground() in my service but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the answer, I think my question was a little convoluted to begin with, so I'll try to answer the various parts, as well as adding my actual solution....

I had an `Activity` that was starting a `Service`. The `Service` (which included an `AsyncTask`) was supposed to run in the background, monitoring the accelerometer and counting down a timer. The `Service` was then periodically sending a broadcast `Intent` to the `Activity`, when the broadcast contained certain data, the `Activity` needed to run some code. This all needed to happen with the screen off.

My findings are that, yes, when hitting the screen lock, the `Activity` does run `onPause()`, but is still fully able to execute code in the internal `BroadcastReciever` class, and consequently this can call methods in the activities main process. I imagine this is a bad way to do things, but it did work.

The issue was with the `AsyncTask` and the `Service`. Regardless of the the way it's set up, (`startForegrond()` etc ) a background thread will be paused for a while when the cpu shuts down (either by pressing the lock key, or waiting for the screen to time out). I found it was paused for intervals of about 1 min.

The answer is to use `PowerManager.WakeLock` and set the flag to `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. This will allow the screen to shut down but keep threads running at full speed in the background.

Doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

dont forget to release it when done as it is expensive on the battery.

Comment: Even my scenario is something similar to this. The View is shown using Windowmanager through a service. I have an Async task which is started if long running task goes on and if in between screen is off and switched on immediately, and that task is still not complete, then launcher shows up and below that lock screen is coming. The logs reveal that `onPause` of launcher is getting after the keyguard is shown. Need help on this :)

Comment: How do I make the keyguard come on top of the launcher ?